# Jmeter regex extractor alternate option for lookbehind

Tags: regex, jmeter, response-headers

I am trying to extract the value of session id from the response header.Is there an alternate way other than using lookbehind in jemeter?
I verified my regex in regexformatter and its working as expected but as jmeter is not supporting lookbehind, the solution is not working for me.

Response header :

```
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
x-session-id: 1a5e099f-5234-4
X-Application-Context: test:8080
```

Regex used is:

```
  (?<=x-session-id: ).{0,16}
```

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Use `x-session-id: *([0-9-]+)` and the `$1$` as template value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configuration should be this one:

[image: Regular Expression Extractor configuration]

Regex:

> x-session-id: (.*)

Comment: Thankyou @UBIK LOAD PACK .That worked.  I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

As per [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of the [JMeter User Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html):

> **Note that `(?<=regexp)` - lookbehind - is not supported.**

So you can just use something like: `x-session-id:\s+(.+)` and it should work fine:

[image]

More information: [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the last character in the session id will be digits. Then you can use the following. If you think the second group in session id will be digits then replace second `\w+` with `\d+` and it will serve the purpose. Let me know if you think the other dataset may fail this regex.

**Regex:**`(?:\w+-\w+-\d+)`

Seems like you have an understanding about Regex so not mentioning the explanation. Let me know if this does not work for you. I will try to come up with another approach but in that scenario please give more datasets.  Good Luck.